# Java Implementing ActionListener methods in Constructor

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, keylistener

Im trying to call my keyPressed method that I created (override) in my constructor for a game I am making to allow an object to move. I implemented ActionListener and KeyListener in the main class.

Is this even possible? I tried calling the method by `this.keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` but I don't know how to initialize e.

What would be the best way to do something like this?

```
Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
public Game(Main game) {

    this.game = game;
    gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(startButton);

    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.setFocusable(true); 
    this.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    this.getContentPane().add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    this.setSize(1000, 1000);
    this.setVisible(true);





    }

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        game.move("u");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        game.move("d");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        game.move("r");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        game.move("l");
        break;
    }
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object src = e.getSource();

    if (src == timer) {
        game.updateBoard();
        if (game.gameEnded()) {
            timer.stop();
            }
        repaint();

    } else if (src == startButton) {

        if (timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
        } else {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while(!game.gameEnded()) {
    game.updateBoard();
    KeyEvent e = null;
    this.keyPressed(e);
}
```

If your constructor is called with the Swing Event-Dispatching-Thread, it blocks it, and no event can therefore be dispatched.

The correct way should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`, which fires an `ActionEvent` periodically.

```
int period = 1000;//fire ActionEvent every second
Timer timer = new Timer(period,new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //do your stuff, for example
        game.updateBoard();
    }
});
timer.start();
```

You shouldn't invoke the methods in EventListener by yourself since they should all be handled by the Event-Dispatching-Thread.

Comment: Thanks @Judger that was helpful. Should I automatically start the timer after creating it? I am overriding `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e).` I created a timer globally at the beginning of the class `Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);` I am calling this as well in the first line of my `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method `Object src = e.getSource();`

Comment: I just edited question with changes. Would something like this work?

Comment: I don't think you can instantiate your `Timer` object like this using `this` as one argument. You should initialize it in the constructor.